# "[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one"

Tags: dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJyng.png)

[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
elinoterdaeme@MBP-de-Eli hygea % cd ios
elinoterdaeme@MBP-de-Eli ios % ls
Flutter
Podfile
Podfile.lock
Pods
Runner
Runner.xcodeproj
Runner.xcworkspace
RunnerTests
firebase_app_id_file.json
elinoterdaeme@MBP-de-Eli ios %